# Get a list of projects/references within a Visual Studio 2010 Extension

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-extensions

I'm creating a Visual Studio 2010 extension package (`Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package`) that needs to analyze all of the projects and those project's references.  I would assume that this is done with a service (e.g. `Package.GetService(typeof(IMenuCommandService))`).  What I need is the interface that contains the functionality to get a list of projects and references for those projects.  Also, any advice on where to find a reference that contains the available interfaces within visual studio would be much appreciated.

Note that I've seen multiple people trying to do something similar using DTE from a macro.  That's not what I'm trying to do.  I'm trying to do the same thing from within a Visual Studio Extension.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So even though you're doing this as part of an extension, you'll still need to use the DTE APIs to get all of the information you want. It may seem backwards but that's just how it works. You should grab the DTE object via `(EnvDTE.DTE)Package.GetService(typeof(SDTE))`. Once you have a [EnvDTE.Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.project.aspx%28v=vs.100%29), access it's Object member and cast that to a [VSLangProj.VSProject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vslangproj.vsproject%28v=vs.100%29) if it's a C# or VB project. This has the reference information you need.

Comment: This does seem a bit odd, but I've confirmed your answer.  Thank you!

Comment: Yes, the only way to reliably get the information is via DTE. It's silly and backwards, but that's how it works.

Comment: Sometimes you will get not all projects: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33209589/project-names-in-visual-studio-solution-sometimes-are-empty