# Project Names in Visual Studio Solution sometimes are empty

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

In visual studio extension I would like to get all projects and their names:

```
var service = (DTE) Package.GetGlobalService(typeof (SDTE));
var projects = service.Solution.Projects;

foreach (Project project in projects)
//....
```

This approach work nice and neat for exception of one little problem:
project variable returns really exact number of project. But project's full name might be EMPTY if it located in the solution's folder. (I mean the structure of solution when projects are united in the solution's folder)

How to get these project properly?

Comment: Don't understand what you mean. Do you have a repro case of such a problem?

Comment: Solution. Folders in solution. Projects in folders of the solution. Understand ?

Comment: nope, please provide a repro

Comment: 1.Create Solution.
2. Add folder to solution
3. Add project to folder just created.
4. Run code above

Expected: variable project.FullName is not null
Actual result: project.FullName is null

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a solution.
This guy is the Lord of Rings as minimum:
[http://www.wwwlicious.com/2011/03/29/envdte-getting-all-projects-html/](https://web.archive.org/web/20190724214503/http://www.wwwlicious.com/2011/03/29/envdte-getting-all-projects-html/)

---

Relevant information from the blog, in case it goes away (like so many other answers on Stack Overflow):

> DTE2.Solution.Projects will only give you the top level list of items under the Solution so any projects nested within Solution Folders are missed. In order to get at these pesky little worms, you need to burrow into the ProjectItem.SubProject property accessed from the ProjectItems collection on the the Project. Just to cap the whole lot off, if you have nested solution folders, then you need some recursion.

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using EnvDTE;  
using EnvDTE80;

public static class SolutionProjects  
{
    public static DTE2 GetActiveIDE()
    {
        // Get an instance of currently running Visual Studio IDE.
        DTE2 dte2 = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE2;
        return dte2;
    }

    public static IList<Project> Projects()
    {
        Projects projects = GetActiveIDE().Solution.Projects;
        List<Project> list = new List<Project>();
        var item = projects.GetEnumerator();
        while (item.MoveNext())
        {
            var project = item.Current as Project;
            if (project == null)
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (project.Kind == ProjectKinds.vsProjectKindSolutionFolder)
            {
                list.AddRange(GetSolutionFolderProjects(project));
            }
            else
            {
                list.Add(project);
            }
        }

        return list;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Project> GetSolutionFolderProjects(Project solutionFolder)
    {
        List<Project> list = new List<Project>();
        for (var i = 1; i <= solutionFolder.ProjectItems.Count; i++)
        {
            var subProject = solutionFolder.ProjectItems.Item(i).SubProject;
            if (subProject == null)
            {
                continue;
            }

            // If this is another solution folder, do a recursive call, otherwise add
            if (subProject.Kind == ProjectKinds.vsProjectKindSolutionFolder)
            {
               list.AddRange(GetSolutionFolderProjects(subProject));
            }
           else
           {
               list.Add(subProject);
           }
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```